# Moving Minecraft players with command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On the minecraft server Hypixel, there is a minigame called Murder mystery. One of the maps, transporter, has you move through these tunnels automatically with no control, but its not teleporting. I want to do this in a map I'm making, but i can't find the command. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1):

Hypixel is a modded server. They probably just set the velocity of the player in its data, which you can't do in Vanilla Minecraft.

So it's not possible with regular commands.

Answer (score 0):

Hypixel is not a modded server, it is a bungee cord plugin server. I would say the only way to do the in vanilla Minecraft would be with advanced command block skills. I would recommend not doing a two-way tunnel like hypixel has it and instead start with a one-way tunnel.

To keep it basic I would recommend at the starting location to have a repeating command block that `/tp @a[r=2] ~ ~5 ~` to the tunnel which will be five blocks above.

Next, in the tunnel make the entire floor of the tunnel command blocks which trigger on a one-second clock. Put `tp @a[r=1] ~1 ~ ~` (put the number next to the "~" of the coordinate point you want to change. Then when they get to the end of the tunnel they should drop 5 blocks. Make the tunnel only one way unless you are really good a dummy scoreboards.

Comment: Unless the server used is the [official server](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server), it is a server that has modifications which would fall under the modded umbrella.

Comment: Plugins are just a different name for mods. And the question specifically mentions no teleporting. You're not answering the question at all. And in what way is `/tp` "advanced command block skills"?

Comment: I understand that i can do stuff with /tp, but my friend has used a different commmand and hypixel is not using a repetitive /tp. I wanted something smoother than /tp like the way levitation works, except horizontal and exact control. I don't know what my friend's command is

Comment: @zobiechowplayers The command you are looking is probably not a vanilla command.  It is most likely a modified version of Minecraft using a command that is not in vanilla (unmodified) Minecraft command.  This is a reiteration of Fabian's answer.  I suggest you ask your friend what command he used and if it was a modified version of Minecraft.  You can also have a look at the [wiki on commands](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands) to see the commands you can use with vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: @Fabian Perhaps it's not `tp` but it is the use of target selector arguments or relative coordinates that he thinks is advanced.  It all seems easy to you because you are a command wizard.

Comment: Thanks! :D I consider myself more as a programmer and someone who has heard about a lot from real command block wizards. That probably makes it look like I'm one myself.